# Why aren't exit().remove() calls removing elements from my d3-sankey graphic?

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

I'm attempting to work up to a smoothly animated Sankey diagram [in this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-meadow-3x0ue?file=/src/index.js) but right now I'm having trouble even just abruptly redrawing it.  I have attempted to remove nodes, links & gradients via the typical `.enter()` and `.exit()` methods, but it seems like the only way to actually get rid of previously drawn `rect`s, `path`s etc. is to go scorched-earth like so:
[image: lines 130-135 of index.js in the linked codesandbox]

If I comment those out and e.g., switch from the 'everybody' view to the 'changed ppl only' view, or use the arrow buttons to navigate between the 2 months worth of data, nothing in my svg seems to change.

As you can maybe see from the sandbox, there aren't any errors--just no updates.